# Calling a method in another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers in different namespace(a and b), like below:

```
class A::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Technology.all
  end
end

class B::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Technology.all
  end
end
```

The two actions execute the same logic, and I belive it is a repetition. I want to eliminate the repetition, so how can I borrow the code in namespace a like below?

```
class B::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    A::TechnologiesController.method(:index).call self
  end
end
```

Comment: Either make both controllers inherit from a common ancestor (`class A::TechnologiesController < BaseTechnologiesController`) or include a module that provides the methods.

Comment: @Stefan So there isn't a method to borrow the method in another class like javascript?

Comment: In my own opinion, in different controller, you don't need do any mixins. It is more readable.

Comment: You can use ActiveModel::Concern here. You can define one method in concern and include in your controller.

Comment: @Run What do you mean, "like in javascript"? You can call a **static**(!!) method from another class in both languages, but this method is not - and cannot be - static.

Answer (score 3):

Answering an implicit question stated in comments: there is an ability to borrow the method with [`UnboundMethod#bind`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) *if and only* the object calling `bind` `is_a?()` instance of the class the method belongs to:

```
def index
  A::TechnologiesController.instance_method(:index).bind(self).()
end
```

but this is neither idiomatic nor readable. One should either use a mixin:

```
module Mixins::TechnologiesController
  def index
    render json: Technology.all
  end
end

class A::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  include Mixins::TechnologiesController
end
class B::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  include Mixins::TechnologiesController
end
```

or a common ancestor:

```
class Base::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Technology.all
  end
end
class A::TechnologiesController < Base::TechnologiesController; end
class B::TechnologiesController < Base::TechnologiesController; end
```

---

Bonus track: in Rails one might use [`Module#delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) monkeypatch.

---

Bonus track #2: the implementation on procs stored as constants:

```
class A::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  INDEX = -> { render json: Technology.all }
  def index
    INDEX.()
  end
end

class B::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    A::INDEX.()
  end
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did, thanks! `[INFO] bound to the answer.`

Comment: The first code raise: TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of A::TechnologiesController.

Comment: Although it is *clearly* overkill in this instance, one could also use a presenter, no?

Comment: @jvillian: nope, presenters don't seem applicable here too. But maybe I'm not seeing the same as you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Run indeed, the object should be an instance of the source class. I never knew that before because nobody writes code in Ruby that way.

Comment: @mudasobwa If it must be a instance of the source class, it is not need to borrow.

Comment: Maybe just drop the first part altogether. Seems out of place now. If we're rebinding a method of another instance of the same class, might as well use our own method :shrug:

Comment: Again, *way* overkill for this instance. But, you could have a `TechnologyIndexPresenter` with a method `present` that does `render json: Technology.all`. Then call `TechnologyIndexPresenter.present(self)` in each of the `index` methods of the `controllers` in question. You would *never* do it in this case. But perhaps if the logic was more complex.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nope. Check the example in the documentation. It makes a perfect sense in class hierarchy when one borrows a method from the middle of the hierarchy chain and tries to bind it to the instance of class _being an ancestor_.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of a [mixin](https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-mixins-2/).
With this you can DRY up your code and you don't have to call the method of another controller.

Here is the module:

```
module CommonInterface
  def render_technology
    render :json, Technology.all
  end
end
```

And this would be your controller

```
class B::TechnologiesController < ApplicationController
  include CommonInterface
  def index
    render_technology
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide a complete answer; simple links are not welcome on SO, [according to ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So there isn't a method to borrow the method in another class like javascript?

Comment: @Run: this is possible in ruby, but it's not done. Unlike javascript, ruby has good tools for sharing functionality.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you provide the borrowing style?

Comment: “can you provide the borrowing style?”—what’s wrong with my answer? I doubt @SergioTulentsev might invent something more fashionable, but let’s see :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Yes, y̶o̶u̶r̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶, I would have posted the same as you, but apparently it's not applicable here ( but I noted the level of your opinion of me )

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nah, I left a room for a little chance. BTW, my answer was not 100% correct, one can not bind an unbound method to an arbitrary instance.

Answer (score 0):

The ancestor and mixin answers are really good if you do want to DRY things up, but in my opinion you don't necessarily have to. The `render json:` bit belongs in the controller action. You expect your action to render something in both controllers.

The query is something that might change in the same way over time I guess `Technology.all`, so you could abstract that somewhere, but again, it might be a good idea to wait and see if that is the case.

If you do go with mixins or a base class, you will couple the two controllers, which might be fine. But again, you might just want to take this decision later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the above problem by making a super method in the ApplicationController
and you need to add one more method in each controller to pass the values to super method you can not only used for Technology model you can also used it for any other model.

For sample example

In the application controller

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      def index
        @collection = model
      end
    end
```

In each controller we can call the above method like this

```
    class StudentsController < ApplicationController

      def index
        super
      end

      def model
        Student
      end
    end




    class JobsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        super
      end
      def model
        Job
      end
    end
```

The data you will recived in the @collection that can be used in the views for example

For the app/views/students/index.html.erb

```
    <% @collection.all.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.Name %></td>
        <td><%= student.Email %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

For the app/views/jobs/index.html.erb

```
    <% @collection.all.each do |job| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= job.id %></td>
        <td><%= job.exp %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```